# Inserting records into Table A from Table B only if they are not avaiable in Table A

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.. Table A and Table B (MySQL)

```
Table-A has id,value,name..    and 
Table-B has id,name,email,address..
```

I like to insert 'id' from Table B as 'Value' in Table A only if that 'id'(TableB) does not exist as'Value' in TableA

So can i use this

```
INSERT INTO `TableA`( `value`,  `name`) 
SELECT id,name FROM TableB 
WHERE TableB.id NOT IN TableA.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code along the lines of the following:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TableA where TableA.value = TableB.id)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `TableA`( `value`,  `name`) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id,name FROM TableB 
WHERE TableB.id = TableB.value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value, name)
SELECT b.id, b.name
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a ON b.id = a.value
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Comment: i feel this may go to never ending loop or query? since its taking some time..(3 million records) :-)

Comment: You may want to `INSERT` incremental amounts at a time. You could add `LIMIT 100000` after the `WHERE`. Also, how long does the `SELECT` by itself take?